# Contours not exporting correctly from ArcGIS Pro to DGN

Tags: arcgis-pro, contour, dgn

I'm running into a problem when using the Export to CAD tool. When I run my contours through the tool it is not exporting all of them to the DGN (seed: template3d_US_Feet). I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong here as the tool doesn't have many options. [image]

The red contours are the DGN and the blue are the feature class.

Comment: too many vertices for the DGN file. you need to generalize your data first limit is 5000, but real limit is 5456 per line.